Cant initialize model in sequelize Typescript
I'm trying to connect my Nodejs TypeScript Project to a MySQL database using Sequelize and Sequelize-Typescript, but I cant get sequelize to initialize my database model. Whenever I start the project, it throws the following error:
TypeError: Cannot convert undefined or null to object
    at Function.getOwnPropertyDescriptor (<anonymous>)
    at /home/janneck/WebstormProjects/SchoolService/node_modules/sequelize-typescript/dist/model/column/column.js:18:131
    at __esDecorate (/home/janneck/WebstormProjects/SchoolService/dist/models/documentType.model.js:13:40)
    at /home/janneck/WebstormProjects/SchoolService/dist/models/documentType.model.js:67:9
    at /home/janneck/WebstormProjects/SchoolService/dist/models/documentType.model.js:73:7
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/janneck/WebstormProjects/SchoolService/dist/models/documentType.model.js:75:3)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1376:14)
    at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1435:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1207:32)
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1023:12)

This is my model definition:
import { Column, DataType, Model, Table } from "sequelize-typescript";

@Table({ tableName: "DocumentType" })
class DocumentType extends Model {
  @Column({ type: DataType.STRING, primaryKey: true })
  public documentTypeId: string;

  @Column(DataType.STRING)
  public name: string;
}
export default DocumentType;

The project normally contains more than just this one model, but after seeing the error message say something about the DocumentType Model, I decided to try initializing just this one model without any relations to the other ones.
I am really out of ideas here and I have no clue what could be the issue. I've used sequelize-typescript in a different project before but in this project I just can't get it to work.
These are the versions of typescript-sequelize and sequelize:
    "sequelize": "^6.37.1",
    "sequelize-typescript": "^2.1.6"


Hi - did you resolve this, because I'm having the same issue

Hi, unfortunately I didnt resolve this :/ I ended up switching to TypeORM instead of sequelize, since the project where I had this issue was still at the very beginning so it was still an option to switch. TypeORM overall worked much better than squelize with typescript, at least in my experience. If you do happen to find a solution other than switching the ORM, please let me know! I'd still really like to know what the problem was

I resolved it, but I'm not sure which thing was the fix because I had so many errors. It may have been that I was importing from 'sequelize' when I had to import from 'sequelize-typescript' - notice that you also have to initialize the sequelize instance using sequelize-typescript's import instead of just sequelize.

I'm pretty sure I did initialize using sequelize-typescript, but it's been a few weeks so I can't exactly remember. At least we both found a solution in the end :)
